# Vector rendering issue using Mapbox-gl & GeoServer vector tiles (pbf)

Tags: geoserver, mapbox-gl-js

I am rendering a vector line in the browser using mapbox-gl. The layer is being served using GeoServer as a pbf vector tile.

The rendering issue is happening at most zoom levels and it is happening on the tile borders (when I load a raster layer, the tiles 'seams' are at the exact same spot as the vector rendering issue (image below)).

[image]

The Mapbox-gl source definition:

```
  var vectorLayerSource = GEOSERVERURL + 
    '/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' +
    myLayerName +
    '@EPSG%3A900913' +
    '@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf;

  // Vector source
  map.addSource('projectVectorSource', {
    'type': 'vector',
    'scheme': 'tms',
    'tiles': [vectorLayerSource]
  });
```

When I render the exact same layer in Mapbox-gl as a geoJSON the issues does not exist.

Comment: Looks like I am suffering from this issue: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-7920